# Common uses of AI techniques

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I am a build engineer in my current position but I dabble in applying AI techniques to improve our capabilities.   What I am interested in is how your teams use AI Techniques (Pattern Recognition, Machine Learning, Bayesian Classification, or Neural Networks) in real life.  I am looking for ideas on other ways of improving our processes and fun projects to start.

Examples of things I have tried:

- Naive bayesian classifier for automatically assigning class labels (misdemeanor, felony, traffic violation) to free form text entered by court reporters.
- Generated team schedule for the year using a genetic algorithm using a fitness function that assigned demerits for any scheduling conflicts, over / under allocation of team members, holidays, personal time off.
- Binary associative memory for quickly querying environment configuration information for all applications deployed to all environments; including URLs, ports, source control location, environment, server, os, etc

Comment: What are the interesting applications for many of the most popular AI techniques?

Comment: This sort of question is too open-ended for Stack Overflow, sorry.

Comment: How can I make it more specific?  I am just looking for some fun applications / projects to do.  This isn't rocket science :)  A number of the techniques are very simple to implement.

Comment: Can we mark it community wiki instead.  I don't need the rep I would still like to read the discussion.  I have seen more open ended questions on this site on topics that I don't find nearly as interesting. I would appreciate any votes to reopen or a moderator to mark it wiki. Thanks